# R Code in attach()/detach() not work

Tags: r

```
age <- seq(10, 100, 10)
df <- data.frame(age)
df
```

this doesnt work

```
df$agegroup <- vector(mode = "character", length = nrow(df))
attach(df)
agegroup[age >= 10 & age < 20] <- "10To20"
detach(df)
df$agegroup
```

this works fine

```
df$agegroup <- vector(mode = "character", length = nrow(df))
df$agegroup[df$age >=10 & df$age < 20] <- "10To20"
df$agegroup
```

Can somebody explain why is that? thank you!

Comment: Pro tip: avoid `attach()` and `detach()`. Use `with()` and `within()` for functions that don't have a `data=` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the documentation of [`attach`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/attach.html):

> The database is not actually attached. Rather, a new environment is created on the search path and the elements of a list (including columns of a data frame) or objects in a save file or an environment are copied into the new environment. If you use `<<-` or `assign` to assign to an attached database, you only alter the attached copy, not the original object. (Normal assignment will place a modified version in the user's workspace: see the examples.) For this reason `attach` can lead to confusion.